# Accessing a public static arrayList of a Thread Class from another Thread's Class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to access the

```
public static List<ChatThread> Chat_list of my ChatThread Class
```

from the run() method of my Client Class but i keep getting an empty array(Infact it throws an exception at that point : `Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException`)

and am very certain that that arrayList exists and is not empty(Because i did a test on the arrayList in my ChatThread Class). Just take a look at my code.
Please I need your help on what to do.

Thanks.

This is the class containing the arrayList :

```
public class ChatThread extends Thread {


private Socket sc;
private String cherry_name;
private String passwd;
public static List<ChatThread> Chat_list = new ArrayList<ChatThread>(); //THE STATIC ARRAY LIST
private BufferedReader br;
private BufferedWriter bw;
public ChatThread(Socket sc){
    try {
        this.sc=sc;
        System.out.println(sc);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sc.getOutputStream()));
        String help = br.readLine();
        this.cherry_name=help.split("@")[0];
        this.passwd=help.split("@")[1];
        System.out.println(this.cherry_name);
        System.out.println(this.passwd);
        Chat_list.add(this); //This is where i add it to the arrayList
        if(Chat_list.isEmpty()) //This is where i did the test
            System.out.println("I am empty");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){
//Comparaison of information with that in the database    
try{
                    bw.write("success");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();

            while(true){

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

public Socket getSc() {
    return sc;
}   

public String getCherry_name() {
    return cherry_name;
}


}
```

> As for the Client class :

```
public class Client extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader br;
private BufferedWriter bw;
 private ChatThread th;
 private String cherry_name;
 public Client(String cherry_name,String passwd){
 try
 {
     socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
     this.cherry_name=cherry_name;
     br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
     bw.write(cherry_name+"@"+passwd);
     bw.newLine();
     bw.flush();
 }
catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Erreur lors de la lecture du socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run()
 { 
        try {
            String help = br.readLine();
     if(help.equals("failed")){
         this.notify();
         this.destroy();
         socket.close();
         }
     else{
         if(ChatThread.Chat_list.isEmpty()) System.out.println("Empty array!!!"); //This is where it says the array is empty whereas it wasn't the case in the ChatThread Class
         for(ChatThread ct : ChatThread.Chat_list){
                    if(cherry_name.equals(ct.getCherry_name())){
                        th=ct;
                        break;
                    }
         }
         while(true){

         }

         }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error whilst reading from the socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Interruption");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public Socket getSocket() {
    return socket;
} 
}
```

And my server class :

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    ServerSocket server =new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket sc;
    System.out.println("Server Started");
    while(true){
            sc=server.accept();
            System.out.println("New Connection");
            new ChatThread(sc).start();
    }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

A main class to instantiate the Client class :

```
public class help {

public static void main(String[] argv)  {

new Client("Jerry","Smith").start(); 
}

}
```

Comment: What makes you so certain it isn't null and that it doesn't contain null elements? Show some code so we can see what's going on. Also, add the stack trace for the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You need (at least) to show the code that accesses the arraylist and how you instantiate each relevant object (the arraylist and the 2 threads).

Comment: I did a test in the class containing the arrayList and it wasn't empty...I'll add the code right away

Comment: Every access to a mutable object shared between two threads must be accessed in a synchronized way. Not synchronizing will lead to visibility and coherence issues like you're seeing.

Comment: I have synchronized it but nothing has changed

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Every access to a mutable object shared between two threads must be accessed in a synchronized way. Not synchronizing will lead to visibility and coherence issues like you're seeing.

You should not expose an `ArrayList` like that (even without multiple threads, public static mutable objects are already a very bad practice). Instead, you should encapsulate it in your own object, and make sure every access is synchronized properly.

It's hard to give a more concrete advice without seeing any line of your code.

Comment: I just added my code to the question. Please take a look at it